# How to release a JSONConnection object

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using a `JSONConnection` object as follow.

```
- (void)startGettingSearchResultsByKeyword:(NSString *)keyword
                              delegate:(id <DataProviderDelegate>)delegate
{

    /* Prepare request */
    JSONConnection *jsonConnection = [[JSONConnection alloc] initWithURLString:NSLocalizedString(@"GET_SEARCH_RESULTS", nil)];

    [jsonConnection.requestValues setObject:APP_VERSION_VALUE forKey:APP_VERSION_KEY];
    [jsonConnection.requestValues setObject:keyword forKey:KEYWORD_KEY];

    /* Send asynchronnous URL request and process response */
    [jsonConnection sendAsynchronousRequestWithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *responseValues, NSError *error) {

        NSArray *responseDataArray = [[responseValues objectForKey:JSON_RESPONSE_DICTIONARY_KEY] JSONValue];

        NSMutableArray *searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        if ([responseDataArray count] > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < [responseDataArray count]; index++) {
            NSDictionary *result = [responseDataArray objectAtIndex:index];

                ProductDetails *searchResult = [[ProductDetails alloc] init];

                NSNumber *contentId = [result objectForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"CONTENT_ID", nil)];

                searchResult.contentId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [contentId intValue]];            
                searchResult.productName = [result objectForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"NAME", nil)];

                [searchResults addObject:searchResult];
                [searchResult release];
            }
        }

        [delegate didFinishGettingSearchResults:searchResults];

        [searchResults release];

    }];
}
```

I have no idea about the correct place to `release` my `JSONConnection` object.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to autorelease the JSONConnection when you allocate it?

```
JSONConnection *jsonConnection = [[[JSONConnection alloc] initWithURLString:NSLocalizedString(@"GET_SEARCH_RESULTS", nil)] autorelease];
```

Comment: Nop. I hadn't. So, I added autorelease and it's working fine. thanks.